# LPWSTR typedef and macro?

Tags: c++, string, windows, winapi

I know that `LPWSTR` is a `WCHAR *` (from wtypes.h):

```
typedef WCHAR *LPWSTR;
```

but I can't find the definition for `LPWSTR(s)`. Is a macro / a constructor / something else? Where is it defined?

In particular, are these two lines exactly equivalent?

```
LPWSTR a = (LPWSTR) b;   // cast
LPWSTR a = LPWSTR(b);
```

or does `LPWSTR(...)` do something else than a cast?

Comment: `LPWSTR(b)` is equivalent to `WCHAR*(b)`..

Comment: @DAle That's not what OP is asking about.. Did you read the question?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I can't find the definition, where (in which .h file) is this defined, or maybe a MSDN link?

Comment: I'm tempted to say: Spare yourself all this winapi crap, just `#define UNICODE` everywhere and use `wchar_t` and `L`-prefixed literals with winapi calls, converting to and from UTF-8 as needed. But of course, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Basj What definition do you want? There is none. Re-read my comment (keeping in mind that `LPWSTR` is a `typedef` to `WCHAR*`).

Comment: That's not the question @FelixPalmen. I just would like to know how is defined LPWSTR(s) (not the typedef itself, for which I already know the definition).

Comment: the `(LPWSTR) b` and `LPWSTR(b)` and `reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(b)` is the same. this is only c++ specific cast

Comment: @Basj I already said that. Just thinking it might be helpful to take a step back and realize what convoluted mess windows' handling of unicode has grown into ;)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius But what is `WCHAR*(b)`? Is it the same as `(WCHAR*) b` ?

Comment: @RbMm is this true in general in C++? `(mytype) a` and `mytype(a)` are the same?

Comment: @Basj it's the "constructor style" syntax of a cast in C++ and invalid in C

Comment: Oh ok @FelixPalmen, did not know that. Is a constructor style cast exactly the same as a cast?

Comment: all this is exactly `reinterpret_cast` . this not generate any binary code. simply make compiler happy

Comment: Ok so this is a general rule that I can remember in C++? `mytype(a)` (function-style cast) and `(mytype) a` (C-style cast) are exactly equivalent?

Comment: yes, this is equivalent. you can view for example assembly code, how this line converted, for understand that this is the same

Comment: @Basj I think the issue would've been "more obvious" with only the C++ tag, so please add only one language tag in the future (with the known exceptions like e.g. interfacing one language to another of course).

Comment: Better use `LPTSTR`

Comment: @i486: What exactly is better about writing code, that *may* be compatible with Windows 95? In 2017.

Answer (score -3):

If b is an instance of class B

```
LPWSTR a = (LPWSTR) b;   // call to operator B::LPWSTR()
LPWSTR a = LPWSTR(b);    //  call to B::operator()
```

Comment: 1. `LPWSTR` is a pointer. 2. Even if `LPWSTR` were a class, `LPWSTR(b)` would *not* be calling `operator()`, it would be calling a constructor.